# VBA Looping to Newly Created Tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to create tax statements that look exactly alike in format, but have different values (using vlookup formulas) based on the information that I've entered into the "Sheet1" tab, and then print these statements to PDF after all of the worksheets have been created. I am running into an issue (see code below) where each worksheet that is created is keeping the number found in cell A4 on "Sheet 1" instead of moving down the rows so that the number in K1 on each newly created worksheet corresponds to the next row on "Sheet1".

```
Sub TEST()
'
' TEST Macro
'

'
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each MyCell In MyRange
            .Sheets("Sample").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            .Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value

        Next

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    FinalRow = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For x=4 to Final Row
            .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("K1")

        Next


End With

Dim FolderPath As String

FolderPath = "XXX"

For I = 1 To Worksheets.Count

    Worksheets(I).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & "\" & _
    Worksheets(I).Name, openafterpublish:=True

        Next

MsgBox "All PDF's have been successfully exported"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored the code from `With ThisWorkbook` to `End With`

I elimnated the `With` block altogether since it's not needed.

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange
    .Sheets("Sample").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    .Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value
    .Sheets(MyCell.Value).Range("K1") = MyCell.Value  
Next
```